# Java Spring Boot framework - WebClient logging 4xx/5xx body response

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-webclient

I am new to Spring Boot framework's WebClient. How do I only log the 4xx/5xx with its error body only on error, but when success, return back the `clientResponse` as a `String`, and we can later using `gson` to serialize it?

```java
String postResponse =
        post(
            ENDPOINT,
            token,
            request,
            Request.class);

Response response = gson.fromJson(postResponse, Response.class);
```

```java
    private String post(String endpoint, String token, Mono<?> requestBody, Class<?> requestBodyClass) {

      WebClient.Builder webClientBuilder = WebClient.builder();

      WebClient.RequestBodySpec requestBodySpec = webClientBuilder.build().post().uri(uri);
      requestBodySpec.header(
          "Authorization", BEARER_TOKEN_PREFIX + this.accessTokens.get(token));

      return requestBodySpec
        .header("Content-Type", HEADER_VALUE_CONTENT_TYPE)
        .body(Mono.just(requestBody), requestBodyClass)
        .retrieve()
        .bodyToMono(String.class)
        .block();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

May I suggest something like:

```
    private String post(String endpoint, String token, Mono<?> requestBody, Class<?> requestBodyClass) {
        Mono<String> stringMono = WebClient.builder().build()
                .post()
                .uri(endpoint)
                .body(BodyInserters.fromValue(requestBodyClass))
                .exchange()
                .flatMap(SomeServiceImpl::getResultAsStringOrLog4xx5xx);
        
        //get the JSON from the Mono, but you might not want to block
    }
```

(I omitted the headers)

And the actual answer to the question, do perform the logging with something similar:

```
private static Mono<String> getResultAsStringOrLog4xx5xx(ClientResponse response) {
        if (response.statusCode().is2xxSuccessful()) {
            return response.bodyToMono(String.class);
        } else if (response.statusCode().is5xxServerError()) {
            Logger.error(); //up to you
        } else {
//at this point, you can have your logic on error code
        }
        return
    }
```

There are other ways of doing this, hope this can get you started.

Also, try not to block() in your application.

Thank you

Comment: Why not using `block()` ?  The endpoint we are calling it is expecting us to block-sync call it.

Comment: Just a suggestion. The whole purpose of reactive programming is not to block. But if you have your use case, please feel free to. Was just a suggestion. My answer was mainly trying to help with the logging of errors

Comment: Thanks, but with `block()`, how would that look like with `exchange()` and `flatMap()` ?

Comment: Just return  stringMono.block(); on your post method if it is your use case :)

Comment: Thanks, I still cannot figure out how to log the `response.body` on 4xx/5xx errors.  That's exactly what I am looking to log.